# Different background colours in NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout, navigationview

Let's assume we have a basic Navigation Drawer such as we can generate by creating a new Navigation Drawer activity. We have default built items there. Is it possible to set different background colors in the navigation drawer for different items. For example as in photo: everything under Communicate should have grey background color. Any ideas?

[image: Navigation Drawer]

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the text color:
app:itemTextColor="@color/name_you_gave" or app:itemTextColor="#ffffff"

If you want to change icon color:
app:itemIconTint="@color/name_you_gave"

If you want to change background color:
android:background="@color/name_you_gave"

Everything goes inside of NavigationView.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the selected and unselected item background color in default navigation view ,but not change each background item color.if you want to change it then use custom view inside the drawer layout.

Comment: for change  background in default view, code are below

Comment: <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="checked state color" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="your default color" />
</selector>

Comment: used as itemIconTint in Navigation View